# MySql Client's Credentials Packet

Tags: mysql, c

How should the client's credentials packet look when communicating with a MySql server?

I am working on using a microcontroller to communicate with a MySql server on AWS.

Once I open a TCP socket to the server I receive the server's greeting packet. However, I am having trouble with the client's credentials packet.

When I send the packet I created in the code below, I do not receive a response from the server.

As a side note, I do receive the error "Got packets out of order" when I set the packet sequence number to 0 instead of 1. Any ideas?

Server's greeting:

```
4e0000000a352e362e33372d6c6f67006a3300005871507a363d6e3400ffff0802007fc01500000000000000000000542d2364524c65392d752659006d7973716c5f6e61746976655f70617373776f726400
```

Server's Error message:

```
21000001ff8404233038533031476f74207061636b657473206f7574206f66206f72646572

char buf[76];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
buf[0] = 0x4C;
buf[1] = 0x00;
buf[2] = 0x00;
buf[3] = 0x01;
buf[4] = 0x08 | 0x04;
buf[5] = 0x80 | 0x02 | 0x01;
buf[6] = 0x00;
buf[7] = 0x00;
buf[8] = 0xB8;
buf[9] = 0x0B;
buf[10] = 0x00;
buf[11] = 0x00;
buf[12] = 0x35;
char username[] = "username";
size_t usernameLength = sizeof(username);
strncpy(&buf[36],username,usernameLength-1);
buf[48] = 0x00;
char password[] = "password";
size_t passwordLength = sizeof(password);
unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1(password, passwordLength-1, hash);
buf[49] = 0x14;
memcpy(&buf[50],&hash[0],20);
strncpy(&buf[70],"dbname",sizeof("dbname")-1);
buf[75] = 0x00;
```

Comment: This is tantamount to asking for an off-site resource, namely documentation on the communication protocol used by MySQL.  You could think about about using WireShark or something similar to monitor the communications with a regular client.  Or you could get hold of the source for the MySQL library and see how that is set up to work.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this was not an appropriate place to ask the question I had. However, after posting, I did find a very helpful repository on Github here: https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino
The repository contains all of the source code necessary to write a client which connects to a MySQL database. Most importantly, it shows the proper way to hash the password.

I hope this helps other people since there is very little documentation of MySQL provided by Oracle unless you license the software, regular clients don't provide source code, and observing packet traffic provides limited insight into how the handshake process works.